# Additional virtualhost with Websphere apache plugin

Tags: apache, websphere, virtualhost

Current I have Apache Httpd and Websphere with Apache config generated with Websphere apache plugin. What I want to do is write virtualhost which overlap some of move with usage of provy pass, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias test-*-test
    ServerSignature On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /test/ ajp://localhost:1234/test/
</VirtualHost>
```

Earlier in this conf file I have only WebSpherePluginConfig with path.
New virtualhost is working as it should, but unluckily it overrides somehow all plugin config (even for another server aliases). How to make it to only override this specific path.

Answer (score 1):

The first listed virtual host for *:80 is the default.  Add a new first vhost without proxypass, so the vhost in your question will only be used when the hostname actually matches.